# how to import contact list from iphone address book to my application?

Tags: iphone, contact-list

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.

    UIBarButtonItem *btn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:nil];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = btn;

    self.navigationItem.title = @"Contacts";

    sBar = [[UISearchBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,30)];
    sBar.delegate = self;

    [self.view addSubview:sBar];
    sBar.placeholder=@"Search";


    searchedData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    tableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    [tableData addObjectsFromArray:dataSource]; 
}
```

Comment: I tried to edit the question :-P. It was unreadable. Probably you should add more details about what you want here.

Comment: like in my application i have to show all contact list but it should show on my viewtable.

Answer (score 1):

The following Quick Start guide from Apple's iOS docs could get you started on this.

[Address Book Programming Guide for iPhone - QuickStart](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Chapters/QuickStart.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744-CH2-SW1)

It shows you how to import the `AddressBookUI/AddressBookUI.h` headers and open a native people picker, as well as listen for when a person is picked.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement the following table delegate method to actually get your table to display data.

```
    -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

You can find more documentation on `UITableView` [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

`ABPerson` function [ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople] will work here.

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate( );
CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople( addressBook );
CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount( addressBook );

for ( int i = 0; i < nPeople; i++ )
{
    ABRecordRef ref = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex( allPeople, i );
    ...
}
```

After fetching the array of npeople you can display it in your tableView or do whatever you want to implement.